# Как правильно понять задание с memoization

Tags: javascript

Как разработать **функцию** ( аналог Math ) , которая выполняла простые математические операции (сложение, вычитание , умножение , деление) , а предыдущий рассчитанный результат кешировала ( **меморизация , мемойз , memoization** )
* Хорошо сделать мемойз каждого типа операции ( дилення, умножения ...) ?
Я сделал так(мемойз в моем понимании для сложения):

```js
var sumRes, minusRes, multiRes, divRes;

var math = function(operation, op1, op2){
var result;
    switch(operation){
        case "+": sumRes = sumRes ? sumRes + op1 + op2: op1 + op2; result = sumRes; break;
        case "-": minusRes = op1 - op2; result = minusRes; break;
        case "*": multiRes = op1 * op2; result = multiRes; break;
        case "/": divRes = op1 / op2; result = divRes; break;
        default: console.log("The operation must to be only: \"+\", \"-\", \"*\", \"/\"");
    }

return result;
    
};

console.log(math("+", 1, 2));
console.log(math("+", 1, 2));
console.log(math("+", 1, 2));
console.log(math("+", 1, 2));
```

Но боюсь нужно иначе реализовать((

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Мемоизация - это сохранение уже вычисленных значений. Когда функция повторно вызывается с теми же аргументами, она должна вернуть готовое значение, не выполняя повторных вычислений.

```
var calc = (function () {
  var results = {};

  var fs = {
    '+': function (x, y) { console.log('calculation'); return x+y },
    '-': function (x, y) { console.log('calculation'); return x-y },
    '/': function (x, y) { console.log('calculation'); return x/y },
    '*': function (x, y) { console.log('calculation'); return x*y }
  };

  return function calc(op, x, y) {
    return results[x+op+y] = results[x+op+y] || fs[op](x,y);
  }
})();
```

Естественно, `console.log('calculation');` надо убрать - он здесь для демонстрации того, что вычисление происходит только единожды.

Самовызывающаяся функция нужна для того, чтобы сделать переменные `results` и `fs` приватными для функции `calc`.

Comment: А зачем делать переменные results и fs приватными для функции calc ?

Comment: @Vasyok, ну чтобы в них никто не лазил и ничего не портил :)

Comment: Ну и для корректной работы , без этого не будет работать кэширования))

Comment: Спасибо тебе:))